# How to Fix MAVEN ERROR: The JAVA_HOME environment variable is not defined correctly, this environment variable is needed to run this program

Tags: java, windows, maven

I am unable to get apache maven to run locally on my Windows OS & I'm not sure why. I have mapped the system environmental variables as follows & am still receiving an error when I run command `mvn --version` using my command prompt:

```
The JAVA_HOME environment variable is not defined correctly,
this environment variable is needed to run this program.
```

Can anyone tell me what I am missing in terms of successfully updating my system environmental variables so that I can run maven builds? Please see screenshots of how my system environmental variables & system path variables are configured:

[image: Shows current system environment variables set up]
[image: Shows current system environment path variables set up]

Thank you!

Comment: After saving the environment variables, did you restart your terminal?

Comment: Yep! Always made sure to close the existing command prompt & open another session. I've also confirmed the paths listed are where both the Java JDK & Apache Maven bins are located.

Comment: What does `java --version` output?

Comment: java --version outputs the following: "'java' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file." This is strange given that I've mapped the environmental variables...

Comment: Please check if you have some other mapping to java in you path variable. Secondly, please check if the JAVA_HOME and Path under user accounts are also mapped correctly

Comment: Does `echo %path%` (CMD) or `$env:path` (PowerShell) show the correct Java and Maven directories?

Comment: Also, in addition to Saurabh's suggestion, make sure you've actually applied the new environment variables (e.g., by clicking "Apply" or closing all the dialogs with "OK"). Then try restarting your terminal one more time. If that doesn't work, you can try restarting your computer. Beyond that I'm not sure I can be of more help (though someone else might be).

Comment: @Slaw : I went ahead and added the latest JDK (jdk-17.0.2) instead of my original screenshot & I can confirm that my path shows the latest java & maven directories.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Figured it out - Turns out the users did not have permissions to access the Maven OR Java JDK folders. Updated the permissions & had no issues. Thank you!

Comment: This was definitly the case for me when running on a self-hosted runner and setup-java and setup-maven github actions.  We were caching the `/opt/hostedtoolcache` directory in an azure pool and the permissions were off.  Had to chmod it.